# In R how to I set a the names of a named vector inside an attribute

Tags: r, r-haven

I am reading data into R from SPSS using `haven`.  One of the variables has a `labels` attribute that is extremely long:

```
> attributes(source$VAX8_behavior)
$label
[1] "Which of the following applies to you regarding the COVID-19 vaccine? [8M]"

$format.spss
[1] "F3.0"

$display_width
[1] 7

$class
[1] "haven_labelled" "vctrs_vctr"     "double"        

$labels
                                                                                                       Decline to answer 
                                                                                                                    -999 
                                                                                                          Item not shown 
                                                                                                                    -888 
                                                                                                        Data entry error 
                                                                                                                    -777 
                                                                                                  Failed attention check 
                                                                                                                    -666 
                                                                                                       Lost to follow-up 
                                                                                                                    -555 
                                                                                                        Cannot Calculate 
                                                                                                                    -444 
                                                                           I am not planning to get the COVID-19 vaccine 
                                                                                                                       1 
                                                                           I am considering getting the COVID-19 vaccine 
                                                                                                                       2 
 I am actively planning to get the COVID-19 vaccine (e.g., I have scheduled an appointment to get the vaccine or plan to 
                                                                                                                       3
```

So, I want to change this:

```
attr(source$VAX8_behavior, "labels")[9]
I am actively planning to get the COVID-19 vaccine (e.g., I have scheduled an appointment to get the vaccine or plan to
```

How to I change that to be "... I have scheduled an appointment ..."?  That is, what is the syntax to change the name on a named vector that is an attribute?

This does not work:

```
attr(source$VAX8_behavior, "labels")[9] <- 
  "... I have scheduled an appointment ..."
```

because it sets the value not the label:

```
$labels
                                                                                                       Decline to answer 
                                                                                                                  "-999" 
                                                                                                          Item not shown 
                                                                                                                  "-888" 
                                                                                                        Data entry error 
                                                                                                                  "-777" 
                                                                                                  Failed attention check 
                                                                                                                  "-666" 
                                                                                                       Lost to follow-up 
                                                                                                                  "-555" 
                                                                                                        Cannot Calculate 
                                                                                                                  "-444" 
                                                                           I am not planning to get the COVID-19 vaccine 
                                                                                                                     "1" 
                                                                           I am considering getting the COVID-19 vaccine 
                                                                                                                     "2" 
 I am actively planning to get the COVID-19 vaccine (e.g., I have scheduled an appointment to get the vaccine or plan to 
                                                                               "... I have scheduled an appointment ..."
```

I am guessing the solution needs `setNames()` or `mostattributes()`.

Sorry I can't provide a ReprEx because I don't have SPSS and the data is confidential.

Comment: What exactly does "This does not work" mean? An unexpected result, an error, ...? What does `str(attr(source$VAX8_behavior, "labels"))` return?

Comment: Are you looking for `names(attr(source$VAX8_behavior, "labels"))[9] <- ...`?

Comment: Perfect Roland. It is so obviously now that I see it.  Can you post that answer as a solution so I can mark this is as the right answer?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the [`base::attributes()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/attributes) function can only get/set the attributes of a vector instead of changing the actual individual attributes.

Since we are trying to change the `$labels` attribute of this vector and the attribute returns a list, you'll want to use an setter function like [`base::names()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/names) to modify name of the list returned by the attribute `$labels`.

```
names(attributes(source$VAX8_behavior, "labels"))[9] = "... I have scheduled an appointment ..."
```